# django forms add extra field only on add

Tags: django, django-forms

is it possible to create an extra field on a form only when the form is adding an entry and not editing one.  I guess this would be something on the **init** function with a check on whether instance had been set or not.  Currently my form looks like this

```
class AreaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    any_locations = forms.BooleanField(label="Does this area have any locations?", 
                                       initial=True, 
                                       required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Area
```

but I only want the `any_locations` field there when I'm adding an entry and not editing it.  I guess I could have 2 forms but wondered if there was a neater way?

Comment: What about 'fields' property of Meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check if the form has an instance. If not add in the extra field

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AreaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' not in kwargs:
            self.fields['any_locations'] = forms.BooleanField(label="Does this area have any locations?", initial=True, required=False)
```

Comment: This is an interesting issue, but adding fields like this is not working for me. the field is never added into the form even if i don't use the 'if' clause. I'm using Django 1.9.6 Could be this the problem?